# "Invalid Client detected at address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (my computer IPv4 address)" for an app

Tags: sql-server, iis, ip, server

I am debugging an app. The whole system to keep the app running includes:

```
 client <=> server <=> database
```

The client takes in finger print info and save it to the database pointed by the server.

Once the server is installed, my base url for the server is automatically set as: `http://localhost:8097/WEB-key/Main` with a site ID and admin ID. Basically the site ID and admin ID are inputs in the client app to link to the server.

but when I run the app on the client end, it tells me:

> "Invalid Client detected at address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (my computer IPv4
>   address)"

The IPv4 address is valid and supported by apache, reading "It works!"

Can anyone tell me why possibly this IPv4 is involved in the app? thanks!

Comment: localhost is transformed to an IP Address, I suppose 127.0.0.1 but could change.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Allow Client Debugging in webkey Site Management properties

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12010188)

Comment: @mort How does this not attempt to provide an answer?